# VB.NET How to get row values from database to textbox (multiline)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have this code (found it somewhere on the net, maybe even here on stackoverflow)

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT User FROM T1 WHERE User IS NOT NULL;"
Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\db2.accdb")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        TextBox1.Text = reader(0).ToString()
    End While
    reader.Close()
End Using
```

In my database I have 3 users but when I am running this code only the last one is showed in the textbox.

Let's say my table looks like this

```
User

one
two
three
```

But my textbox shows only "three"

How can I export and show all rows from column User and separate them with new line?

And if it is easy I would like to have a code for a list box. You know, like get column name (with sql query) and for every row make a new item in listview.

PS: the code works fine, just need to be adjusted. I am working with databases in vb.net for like 3 days, so my question might be easy, but still difficult for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  While reader.Read()
     TextBox1.Text &= reader(0).ToString() & Environment.NewLine 
  End While
```

Also make sure to set  TextBox1.Multiline = true